# Mobile Safari Leading/Line-height problems (using @font-face)

Tags: css, mobile-safari, font-face

I'm developing a responsive site and don't have a mobile device myself. (Still living in the dark ages as it were)  Anyway, my colleague has sent me a screen shot of the site on an ipad.

The leading/line-height is awful, but looks fine in regular Safari.  Here's some of the pertinent (I think) CSS:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'Rubrik-Regular';src: url('fonts/237360_5_0.eot');src: url('fonts/237360_5_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('fonts/237360_5_0.woff') format('woff'),url('fonts/237360_5_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; }
@font-face {font-family: 'Rubrik-Medium';src: url('fonts/237360_6_0.eot');src: url('fonts/237360_6_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('fonts/237360_6_0.woff') format('woff'),url('fonts/237360_6_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; }
@font-face {font-family: 'Rubrik-Bold';src: url('fonts/237360_7_0.eot');src: url('fonts/237360_7_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('fonts/237360_7_0.woff') format('woff'),url('fonts/237360_7_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; }

html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} 

html{font-size:81.25%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:81.25%;-ms-text-size-adjust:81.25%}  /* shrink to ~13px body font without changing all other sizes */
/* 16px base font size with 162.5% (26px) line height */
body, button, input, select, textarea { font: 1em/1.6154em 'Rubrik-Regular', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; color: #262626; }
```

Here's a side by side comparison:

[image: Mobile vs Desktop Safari]

[live demo link](http://client.kathyisawesome.com/seattle-art-museum/)

Why isn't the line height being respected?

Comment: Did you already get this resolved? I looked at it in iOS Simulator (an official Apple tool) and the line height looks fine.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Nick. I kept working on it and finally stumbled across my error in -webkit-text-size-adjust.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have resolved it:

```
html{ font-size: 16px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%}
```

I had mistakenly tried to adjust the font size down like so:

```
html{ font-size: 82.5%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:82.5%; -ms-text-size-adjust:82.5%}
```

And the size adjust parameter was sneakily killing my typography on mobile devices.